# Is it possible to resend image url received from server back to it as an image after processing

Tags: angularjs, image

I have a remote server which has profile data and an image and when I retrieve it, I get the image url, which I can display using the `<img>` tag, by using the url.
When I have to modify the details, I send a new image, for which I upload a new image using a small AngularJS function and send the whole data using formData and http request.

But, out of curiosity, I was wondering whether there is any way to send an object of the same image using the url I received from the server.

Another reason I thought of it was that I was thinking of maybe changing its dimensions,etc.

Just in case if I ever needed to generate a thumbnail of the image of a smaller size in future.

Comment: I don't know if I really understood. Do you mean that you receive an image url from the server and then you modify this image in the browser (using html5 api or whatever) and then you want to send back the image file to your server?

Comment: No , that is what i want to achieve, the update part along with sending an image again to the server.Basically ,  I receive the url , i wanted to know how can i use the url to generate the image and then modify it maybe or send it as it is while modifying as a new picture,(if possible: without having to save the image locally )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself by looking around and generating a canvas from the url, through dataURI by using the function :

```
        var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
        var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
        var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
        for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
            ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var blob= new Blob([ab], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
```

to create a blob to send the image back after scaling(was required).